# Python abstractclass Inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, metaclass

I have two class structured as below

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class C(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    """"""

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def x(self):
        """Get the _x"""

    @x.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def x(self, value):
        """Set the x"""

    @property
    def y(self):
        """Get the _y"""

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        """Set the _y"""


class D(C):
    """"""

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @C.x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @C.y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self._y = value
```

When I initialize an instance of D. It throws a error:
**TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class D with abstract methods x**

When I rewrite setters decorator in D as

```
@x.setter
def x(self, value):
    self._x = value
```

it works. But in python abc document https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html it states:
in disappreciated @abc.abstractproperty
If only some components are abstract, only those components need to be updated to create a concrete property in a subclass:

```
class D(C):
    @C.x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        ...
```

I don't know why write in this way will lead to error. Please help me understand the logic here. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `@C.x.setter` above your setter, you're setting `x` to a version of `C.x` with the setter replaced with your new setter function. *Only* the setter - the getter you wrote earlier is discarded. You're still using `C.x`'s abstract getter.

The example in the docs uses `@C.x.setter` because they *want* the behavior it provides. In the doc example, `C.x` has a concrete getter, and they just want to replace the setter. That's not the case in your code.